# Getting white screen when I try to include a new model in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-1.2

I'm trying to create a model that will be for data from CSV imports. There is no associated database table. I've created the file as shown below. The permissions are set identically to the other models. In the controller, if I set uses as

```
$uses = array('DailyOrdersReport');
```

I get a white screen and no errors in apache's error.log, cake's error.log, or cake's debug.log. I've tried setting

```
$useTable = false;
```

but still have the same issue. I've also tried setting up the `$_schema` variable but still no luck.

__

Model:

```
<?php
class DailyOrdersReport extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'DailyOrdersReport';
    public $useTable = false;

    function import($filename) {

    }

}
```

__

Controller:

```
<?php
App::import('Sanitize');
class DailyOrdersReportsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'DailyOrdersReports';
    var $helpers = array();
    var $uses = array('DailyOrdersReport');
    var $components = array();

    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    function index() {
        $filename = "daily-report.csv";
        // $model = ClassRegistry::init('DailyOrdersReport');
        // $daily_orders = $model->import($filename);
        $daily_orders = $this->DailyOrdersReport->import($filename);
    }
}
```

--

Additional Info:

Ok. I've tracked it to /cakecore/cake/libs/configure.php Configure::__load where it attempts to requirethe file. Running file_exists just before require returns true. I tried surrounding with try/catch and also tried require or die. That's where it cuts out. Still no errors.

Comment: Then, you should ask yourself the question, is this really a model

Comment: I'm new to CakePHP but it seems that it would be a model anywhere else. The only difference is that the data it grabs is from a CSV rather than a database.

Comment: Well, then, if it's not another layer of your application, and I'm also not so experienced with CakePHP, I would suggest to turn on the error reporting, in order to see the error, because I suspect only the reporting is suppresed

Comment: php error reporting is on and I've got plenty of feedback from other errors and warnings in the regular log files. I've got cake debug turned on at the controller level and am getting feedback from that until I put in `$uses = array('DailyOrdersReport')`.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose with so little code. Be sure to have debug > 1, and could you post a bigger extract of the model (and the exact name of it), and also a little more of the controller that uses it (just one action where you use it)? Have you tried `ClassRegistry::init('DailyOrdersReport')` or `loadModel('DailyOrdersReport')` with the same results?

Comment: I tried `ClassRegistry::init('DailyOrdersReport')` with the same result

Comment: What version of cake are you using? How come you use `$model->import` instead of `$this->DailyOrdersReport->import()`?

Comment: @Nunser At its core, I believe it is 1.2.8. I'm piggy backing on somebody elses codebase here. As far as the syntax in question, I just had the wrong line commented out there. I tried a few different things to make this work. That should be correct now.

Comment: Maybe stupid but have you tried with a different method name like `_import`?

Comment: is your `DailyOrdersReport::import` method empty? maybe you're outputting something from there that is causing the white screen

Comment: I've tried several different methods within the model. I've even copied over methods from another model. It seems to die long before that.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible for anyone here to debug your problem, as all we can do is guessing, and that's not very constructive, I'm afraid you'll have to trace it down on your own. Start by adding debug output in the code, the whole way from the front controller to the action controller. `index.php > Dispatcher::dispatch() > ::__getController() > ::__loadController() > ::_invoke() > Controller::constructClasses() > ::loadModel() > ::dispatchMethod()`

Comment: Also note that such vague question are usually better suited on IRC or the google group where you can have lengthy discussions.

Comment: I'll make the question as specific as you want it. I feel like it's pretty specific, only leaving out extra code that doesn't pertain to the issue. Do you have questions about this that are unanswered?

Comment: @ndm It's not logging any errors from anywhere at the moment. What debug statements would you add?

Comment: Well, the question is specific in what you are experiencing, but the problem itself is very unspecific, there could be thousands of reasons for the symptoms you are describing, and so this leads to this whole back and forth here in the comments, and this is not really what SO is suited for... it's not that every single question must be as specific as "_my printer won't print anymore, it's on fire, what should I do?_" though.

Comment: By "debug output" I mean just output some dummy data, something like `var_dump('xyz')` so that you can figure at which point the script actually dies, maybe you can pinpoint it down to a specific problem that can be reproduced by someone.

Comment: Ok. I've tracked it to /cakecore/cake/libs/configure.php Configure::__load where it attempts to `require`the file. Running file_exists just before require returns true. I tried surrounding with try/catch and also tried `require or die`. That's where it cuts out. Still no errors.

Comment: if you are using component for the csv helper then make sure trim the space before the component start <?php tag start. sometime this might be an error. i have faced this kind error many time so try it :)

Comment: So it dies on the `require` call, it doesn't make it any further? That indeed sounds as if there is something fishy with the file. Have you tried to include it in a bare PHP file to see if the same happens?  Can you provide that exact file (by uploading it somewhere so that possible problematic chars are being kept intact)?

Comment: @DhavalRajani I have checked that. There are no extra spaces

Comment: @ndm It was an out of place comma from some of the copy and paste code. Ahh!! For some reason, the errors weren't logged when CakePHP was requiring. When I did it in a standalone file, the errors were logged in the apache error.log. If you'll make an answer out of that comment, I'd be happy to accept it. Thank you!